# Django serializers: What does is_valid actually do?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

[git repo](https://github.com/ajmaln/DRF-Chat):
[django tutorial](https://utopian.io/utopian-io/@ajmaln/part-1-creating-a-simple-chat-app-with-djangorestframework)

I've been following the above django project that looks at creating at person to person chat. I've come across this part:

```
def message_list(request, sender=None, receiver=None):
    ...

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print('posting')
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        print(data)
        serializer = MessageSerializer(data=data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='email', queryset=User.objects.all())
    receiver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='email', queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['sender', 'receiver', 'message', 'timestamp']
```

What does `"if serializer.is_valid():"` actually do? Is it checking that the data in the message matches the data in the user profile? I've never used serializers before and could use an explanation of it.

Thanks

Comment: it validates your serializer with the condition of respective field specified in your serializer `MessageSerializer`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call `is_valid` during deserialization process before write data to DB. `is_valid` perform [validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) of input data and confirm that this data contain all required fields and all fields have correct types. If validation process succeded `is_valid` set `validated_data` dictionary which is used for creation or updating data in DB. Otherwise serializer's property `errors` will contain information about errors in input data, and you can send this information as HTTP response in your view.

Comment: I believe `is_valid()` returns `True` or `False` it sets `validated_data` if True and `errors` if `False`.. it returns `return not bool(self._errors)`

Comment: I added the serializer above. Which fields does it check? The sender and receiver or all 4?

Comment: @MicahPearce it will check all 4 fields.

Comment: if `is_valid()` was successful, can we guarantee that `save()` will exit with no errors??